# ImageView work on Android 5 but didn't work on Android 6, how can I fix?

Tags: android, image, imageview

This is my code, I run this application on my lg g3 whit android 5 and it works, but on asus zenfone whit android 6 the image not appear on the screen end appear "image invalid".

```
            selectedImage = null;
            orientation = -1;
            selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            // Get the cursor
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            Cursor cursorF = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, new String[]{MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.ORIENTATION}, null, null, null);
            // Move to first row
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            if (cursorF == null || cursorF.getCount() != 1) {
                orientation = 90;  //Assuming it was taken portrait
            } else {
                cursorF.moveToFirst();
                orientation = cursorF.getInt(0);
            }
            //Toast.makeText(this, "orientation: " + orientation, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);//imgDecodableString = percorso completo immagine
            cursor.close();

            bmpImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgDecodableString);
            bmpImage = RotateBitmap.rotateImageIfRequiredFile(bmpImage, orientation);

            ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
            // Set the Image in ImageView after decoding the String
            imgView.setImageBitmap(bmpImage);
            //name of image
            String sFilePath = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImage);
            String saPathParts[] = sFilePath.split("/");
            String sFileName = saPathParts[saPathParts.length - 1];
            filename = sFileName;
            Toast.makeText(this, "filename:" + filename, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (bmpImage == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Image invalid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because from Android 6 you need to request permissions upon using them, and not when you install the app. You seem to be accessing the user storage, which needs permission. Search for Android Marshmallow Runtime Permissions.

Comment: Could this be the reason, but I do not know how to fix? Can you give me more specific suggestions?

Comment: @PasqualeMoramarco Look here: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: I've read this page, but they are not very experienced, what should I change in code to have the memory read permissions? thank you so much

Comment: @PasqualeMoramarco I'm not sure what you mean exactly. You need to add code to request permission to read from the memory. Try reading this: https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en